# Search and copy missing data across ALL columns between Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

See my following spreadsheet: [dummy spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SO3Z-liX1T61W47gKv5ugWFiQKsHa0-XBQsi1A7dTE0/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to modify a formula to do the following:

- Match the IDs (column A) in Sheet1 and Sheet2
- Copy over the additional data from ALL the columns in Sheet2...into Sheet1

I'm using this current formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A8,{Sheet2!A2:A14,Sheet2!B2:B14},2,0))`

That has allowed me to copy over just one column of data. But I'm wanting to modify the above to copy across ALL columns with one command (if possible).

The sheet I linked to above is obviously just an example. The real data can vary anywhere from 10 columns to 50 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` argument of vlookup needs to be array.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A8,Sheet2!A2:D14,{2,3,4},0))
```

You can create array of sequential numbers with `column`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A8,Sheet2!A2:D14,COLUMN(B1:D1),0))
```